# Remove Time from datetime field in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Same question is available in stack but no answer. I have a dataset `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Date"))`

I need to remove time from this field. Can anyone tell me how??? I tried the following but it did not work

```
Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Date")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Use the Date property of DateTime : ds.Tables[0].Rows[0] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Date").Date

Comment: In c#, there is no `Date` data type, only `DateTime`. Also, `Field<DateTime>` returns a `DateTime`, so the `Convert.ToDateTime` does nothing. What do you mean by did not work?

Comment: The `.Date` property returns a DateTime without the time component. You don't need anything else, especially US-specific string manipulation that's guaranteed to break

Comment: Where are you using this date? Almost all controls allow formatting. You should specify the short date format for your control, MVC helper or data binding expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DateTime` alsways has a date and a time portion. It just has a value without any format. So you are confusing it with it's representation, for example if you call `dt.ToString()`.

You achieve the same what you are doing above without  converting it to `string`, applying a format that only shows the date and finally converting the result back to `DateTime`. You just need to use it's [`Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime yourDateTime = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("Date");
DateTime onlyDate = yourDateTime.Date;
```

But, as said above, this will not remove the hours, minutes and seconds, they are just zeros now. Therefore you have to use one of these:

1. `string onlyDateDisplayed = yourDateTime.ToString("d");`
2. `string onlyDateDisplayed = yourDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`
3. `string onlyDateDisplayed = yourDateTime.ToShortDateString();`

Comment: Far better to set the format property of whatever control is used to display this value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: OP hasn't said that he is using any control that has a format property

Comment: Using a US-only format in a web application is asking for trouble. One can guess what the next two SO questions will be - why doesn't Javascript work and why are the months reversed for some customers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i won't blame op for something i don't  know. Apart from that. All those three approaches above will use the current cultures date format not US. Even the second will use localized date delimiters and only the order of year, month and date is specified. The reason is that / is a special format specifier

Comment: `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Yes, this will not use / as date separator but the current cultures date separator(for me it will display for example 11.24.2017 not 11/24/2017).